# Running Linux Commands from Python on Windows Computer

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am trying to learn how to run command line commands from Python. I am able to do this with DOS:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("dir",shell=True)
```

This is fine, but I need to be able to do this for linux commands because my company uses linux servers. I am using Mobaxterm to run a local linux session. When I try this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("ls",shell=True)
```

I get this error from the terminal:

```
'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Which sounds ridiculous to me, because `ls` is clearly a linux command.

If I don't include `shell=True` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ConsolePractice.py", line 4, in <module>
subprocess.call("ls")
File "C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 560, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File "C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

So what am I doing wrong? How can I get this to work?

EDIT: Thanks for the comments. Python for Windows won't work for what I'm trying to do. I connected to a linux server and did:

```
cat > ConsoleCmd.py
import subprocess
subprocess.call("ls",shell=True)
^C
python ConsoleCmd.py
```

... and `ls` ran. Found the issue. I'll just have to get my scripts on to the server and run them from there. Thanks everyone

Comment: I think you need to install python specific to mobaxterm rather than expect python for windows to pick up mobaxterm's shell builtins

Comment: You are not running linux, you are running windows. The error message says: `not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. `batch` is the windows shell, not to be confused with `bash`. Also the stack trace clearly indicate that your program is run from a windows filesystem `C:\`.

Comment: Are you using mobaxterm's python plugin or some other distribution of python?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I am not using the plugin it is just Python for Windows. These comments helped me realize that I can't use Python for Windows for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by opening an [SFTP Session](http://www.bu.edu/tech/support/research/system-usage/getting-started/get-started-file-transfer/) within Mobaxterm, transferring the python file to the server, then running the file directly on the server (python was already installed on the server).